# Помогите чайнику! Надо упростить код

Tags: json, copy

```
JSON прилетает запрос вида:
{
"e1": "данные"
"e2": "еще"
"e3": "и еще"
"e4": "и "
"e5": "и еще"
}

function doPost(request) {

  var e1 = request.parameter.e1;
  var e2 = request.parameter.e2;
  var e3 = request.parameter.e2;
  .....
getRange(2, 1).setValue(e1);
getRange(3, 1).setValue(e2);
getRange(4, 1).setValue(e3);
.....
```

и так до 100 раз

Как сделать все проще, не очень хочется copy/paste заниматься.

Спасибо.

Comment: for(i=0; i<n;i++) getRange(i+2, 1).setValue(request.parameter["e"+(1+i)]);

Comment: Благодарю! Крепкого Вам здоровья!